# json jquery iteration

Tags: jquery, json

iam newbie here.. please execuse if iam asking wrong question here.
iam developing dynamic page  having two drop down boxes in which second automatically refreshed based on selection of value from first drop down.iam using jquery $.html to automatically refresh second drop down.

```
$("#subcategory").html('<select name="sub_category" class="valid" id="subcategory"><option>Art - Classes</option><option>Beautician Courses</option><option>Computer - Multimedia Classes</option><option>Cooking - Classes</option><option>Hobby - Classes</option><option>Language Classes</option><option>Motor driving - Classes</option><option>Music - Theatre - Dance Classes</option><option>Professional courses - tutions</option><option>Summer - Camps</option><option>Training Instutions</option><option>Tutoring - Private Lessons</option><option>Other Classes</option></select>').show();
```

instead of above one i would like to try with json object and populate second drop down.
my json data will be as below:

```
var data = {
  cat_1: {
    {"id": "1",
    "sub_cat": "sub1"},
   {"id":"2",
   "sub_cat":"sub2"}

  },
  cat_2: {
    {"id": "3",
    "sub_cat": "sub3"},
   {"id":"4",
   "sub_cat":"sub4"}
  }
};
```

if user selects category 1 second drop down should populate value from cat_1.

iam using below code. but i dont know where to restrict or filter based on selection from first drop down

```
 $.each(data, function(index, array,array1) {
               // options[options.length] = new Option(array['variety']);
            options[options.length] =new Option(array['id'],array['sub_cat']);
```

Comment: Have you every looked at KnockoutJS? This low-impact and very powerfull MVVM library allows you to do this with just a couple lines of code. Take a look at www.knockoutjs.com

Comment: Thank you jason. is there any other option or solution..?

Comment: what's `subcategory` could you show us the markup, second where do you made the listener and the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = { 'cat_1': [{ "id": "1", "sub_cat": "sub1" }, { "id": "2", "sub_cat": "sub2"}],
                'cat_2': [{ "id": "3", "sub_cat": "sub3" }, { "id": "4", "sub_cat": "sub4"}]
            };
            //ggg

            $('#ddlCat').on('change', function (e) {
                $('#ddlSubCat').html('');
                if (data[$(this).val()] !== undefined) {
                    $.each(data[$(this).val()], function (i, entity) {
                        $('#ddlSubCat').append($('<option />', { 'value': entity.id, 'text': entity.sub_cat }));
                    });
                }
            });

            $('#ddlCat').trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="subcategory">
        <select id="ddlCat">
            <option value="cat_1">cat_1</option>
            <option value="cat_2">cat_2</option>
        </select>
        <select id="ddlSubCat">
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```